# Why is Jest mock bypassed when trying to mock one function in an ES6 module?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have the following ES6 module that I am trying to mock in a test. Important to note is that I am trying to mock only one function in this module - `createHeadline()`:

```
// ---- HeadlineService.ts ----
import { formatHttpError } from '@http-utils/core';
import axios from 'axios';
import { QueryFunctionContext, useMutation, useQuery, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { Headline } from '../models';

...

export const createHeadline = async (headline: Headline) => {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.post('/headlines', headline);
    return resp.data;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(formatHttpError(e));
  }
};

export const useHeadlineCreate = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation(createHeadline, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      // refetch headlines on success
      queryClient.invalidateQueries('headlines');
    },
  });
};
```

Here's my test where I am using `jest.requireActual` to keep the module intact except for `createHeadline()` which I want to mock:

```
import React from 'react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { Headline } from '../../models';
import { createHeadline } from '../../services/HeadlineService';
import { render, waitFor } from '../../test/test-utils';
import { HeadlineDetail } from './HeadlineDetail';

...

const handleStartNewItem = jest.fn();
const handleItemSelected = jest.fn();
const handleItemUpdated = jest.fn();

// ---- mock createHeadline ----
jest.mock('../../services/HeadlineService', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('../../services/HeadlineService'),
  createHeadline: jest.fn().mockImplementation((headline: Headline) => {
    console.log('-------> createHeadline()')
    return headline;
  }),
}));

const headline = {
  title: 'My headline',
  attribution: 'My attribution',
  teaser: 'My teaser',
};

describe('<HeadlineDetail />', () => {
  test('allows to add a new item', async () => {
    const selectionState = { isNew: true, itemId: '', version: 0 };

    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(
      <HeadlineDetail
        selectionState={selectionState}
        onStartNewItem={handleStartNewItem}
        onItemSelected={handleItemSelected}
        onItemUpdated={handleItemUpdated}
      />
    );

    // add a new item
    userEvent.type(getByLabelText('Title'), headline.title);
    userEvent.type(getByLabelText('Attribution'), headline.attribution);
    userEvent.type(getByLabelText('Teaser'), headline.teaser);
    userEvent.click(getByText('Add'));

    // expect createHeadline() to be called
    await waitFor(() => expect(createHeadline).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));

    // expect handleStartNewItem() to be called to start adding new item
    await waitFor(() => expect(handleStartNewItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
  });
});
```

Unfortunately when the test runs I don't see the console.log in the mock. Instead the original function runs and tries to make a real HTTP call.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the test looks okay, probably the tests proves that there's something wrong with the implementation, unfortunately it's not visible in your question.

I've tried to create some [dummy component implementation](https://github.com/Teneff/so-67406652) and it proves that with a working component implementation the test passes